# How to set value for the linked object of the entity in JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have an Entity "A" which has a `@ManyToOne` link to Entity "B".

```
@Entity
public class A{
private B b;
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = B.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

I have an A object and it's linked B object **both already queried** from the database (by separate queries) and now i need to set B to the A.
I merely do `aObj.setB(bObj)` and see in the logs that it leads to querying B object from the database again (it is stated in logs that ReadObjectQuery is called. maybe it queries object from cache - that doesn't matter - the issue is that some redundand actions happen).
It happens despite the state of A and B, they can be managed or detached, query occurs always.

I understand that i could query A with already set B in one query, etc, but due to legacy code i have an A instance and B instance separately and need to set B to A. Is it possible to set it without redundand database query?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.2

Comment: If you don't want JPA to maintain the links for you, don't map them with object references and set the "B_ID" as an integer or other value directly in A yourself.  Otherwise, JPA has to perform some maintenance when you call setB to make sure that only changes are persisted and pushed to the database.  If you want to avoid some of the access, fetch the associated Bs when you query for A initially using fetch join.

Comment: @Chris Is'nt it possible outside of any transaction?

Comment: An EntityManager must track changes regardless of being in or outside of transactions - you can join it to one at any point and it is expected to flush all changes.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply. I am trying to rewrite application to use JPA instead of the old ORM written by the customer. That ORM wasn't able to perform some kind of the fetch join and that's why the usual way was to query all instances separately and then set them to each other appropriately. I can't remove mapping links because in many places code expects that doing `aObj.getB()` will query the database.
Do i understand you correctly that it is not possible to prevent additional queries when calling `aObj.setB()` if i don't use fetch join and don't remove links mapping?

Comment: If A ist already linked to B in the persistence context and the database, why do you need to link B to A? The link should already exist because JPA requires to always maintain both sides of the same relationship.